# Slow synology transfer - in one direction

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nas, smb, synology-diskstation

I got a Synology Diskstation (220+) and in setting it up, tried copying files to and from it.

I was surprised to see ~500KB/s when transferring files to it from my laptop. I can copy files from the Synology to my laptop at ~70MB/s.

It seems that I should be able to get much faster rates copying to the Synology (and 500KB/s simply won't do).

**Why is it so slow to copy files *to* the Synology?**

I can't find anything online that seems to address this and have run out of things to try.

I've been testing over wifi (802.11ac). I tried AFP (Apple) and SMB (even forcing SMB v1, 2, 3).
I also ran one test wired ethernet (laptop wired into the router) with a different computer and see 100-125MB/s transfer, so the router <> Synology (which is always wired into the router) and the Synology itself seem fine.

To avoid the file protocols and HDDs, I started iperf tests (iperf3 in docker on the Synology):
Synology (wired to router) --> Laptop (802.11ac): 600Mb
Laptop --> Synology: 4Mb

To see if it's something with the wireless network/router itself, I broke out my Raspberry Pi (RPi Zero W) running on the wifi (on the slower 2.4GHz 802.11n network to the same router):
Synology (wired to router) --> RPi (802.11n): 30Mb (clearly it's on the slower network)
RPi --> Synology: 4Mb

RPi (802.11n) --> Laptop (802.11ac): 30Mb
Laptop --> RPi: 30Mb

So the network will definitely sustain 30Mb in any direction and seems like it should be capably of 600Mb when on the 802.11ac. However, copying to the Synology is extremely slow.

The Synology is setup minimally (I was just trying to get the basics working first), DSM 6.2.3 and the DS220+ is an Intel Celeron J4025 CPU, 2 GB RAM.

Comment: Can you factor your WiFi router/ap into the cinnections? It is unclear what devices talk to what devices over WiFi.  Does the Pi speak via router or directly to PC? Is the NAS connecting to router/switch/ap wirelessly or with Ethernet cable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @davidgo, editing question to specify each device's connection to the router.